# PHP's exif_read_data() function causes 500 server error

Tags: php, image, jpeg, exif

For some reason my production server is giving me a 500 server error when running the exif_read_data() function on a jpg image. I have verified that the image is indeed a jpg, exists, and has proper permissions. The function works perfectly on my localhost machine.

What could possibly cause this error?

The server is running PHP 5.3.17, my localhost is running 5.3.8, but I doubt that should make a difference.

Thank you.

EDIT: my simple code.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$path = '/home/user/staging/files/image.jpg';
$exif = exif_read_data($path);
var_dump($exif);
```

Comment: what is in the error log?

Comment: Always check the error log first.

Comment: I'm willing to bet there could be smart/curly quotes in your code, it's a possibility. I.e.: `“` and/or `”`

Comment: I checked /var/log/messages, don't see anything regarding this error.

Comment: Fred: Nope, no quotes at all.

Comment: I've added the code I'm using. It's pretty basic. Any other ideas? Turns out the apache error log is in /etc/httpd/logs, but nothing there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone wondering what the solution was, it was to recompile Apache with the exif module enabled. Apparently it's possible not to have it on by default.